# How to get the proper fixed point iteration function?

Tags: roots, fixed-point-theorems

When we find the approximated root of a function $f(x)$ in an interval $[a,b]$ from the fixed point iteration method, 
we derive a new function $g(x)$ which has a fixed point as a root of $f(x)$. Is there any special strategies to get the $g(x)$ which will converge to the real root rapidly?
I have to find the root between $[1,2]$ interval of the following function.
$$ f(x) = x^3 + 4x^2 - 10 $$
I can get following different functions to do the fixed point iteration.
$$g_1(x) = x - x^3 - 4x^2 +10$$
$$g_2(x) = (\frac{10}{x} - 4x)^\frac{1}2$$
$$ g_3(x) = \frac{1}2(10-x^3)^\frac{1}2$$
$$g_4(x) = (\frac{10}{4+x})^\frac{1}2$$
$$g_5(x) = x - \frac{x^3 + 4x^2 - 10}{3x^2 + 8x}$$

After checking each function for the first derivative, 
$$g_1(x),g_2(x),g_3(x) > 1$$
and $$g_5(x) < g_4(x)< 1.$$

Now I can see that the $g_5(x)$ is the suitable function for the iteration.

How can I get the proper $ g(x)$ without solving the derivative for all the possibilities?

Comment: Your $g_5(x)$ is just the standard Newton iteration.

Comment: Please check your interval. There is no root in [1,2]

Comment: @Amzoti: Yes, your right, took wrong function. Got $x=-1.36523$